# How to convert WKT to SVG

Tags: javascript, php, wkt

I have some Well-known text (WKT) for representing geometry object such as Point, MultiPoint, LineString, Polygon, MultiPolygon etc. I have a multipolygon with in total 40000 Points.

I have found [this plugin to convert SVG to WKT](https://github.com/davidmcclure/svg-to-wkt). Is there any JavaScript or PHP plugin which converts WKT to SVG?

Comment: Time to write one :3 For time being, I found this: http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/docs/examples/wkt.html seems to work only on Chrome...

Answer (score 1):

Use [Wellknown](https://github.com/mapbox/wellknown) to convert WKT to GeoJSON, then use [D3](http://d3js.org/) to convert GeoJSON to SVG.

Source : A comment to the same question you asked here : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72323/how-to-convert-wkt-to-svg

Answer (score 1):

I know its been a long time but you could write one. a conversion between those two is fairly simple.

for example the following simple function converts a WKT polygon

```
    var s = data.split("POLYGON ((");
    var s2 = s[1].substring(0, s[1].length - 2).split(" ");

    var mysvg = "M";
    for (var i = 0; i < s2.length - 2; i += 2) {
        mysvg += (s2[i].substring(0, s2[i].length - 1)) + ",";
        mysvg += (s2[i + 1].substring(0, s2[i + 1].length - 1)) + "L";
    }
    mysvg = mysvg.substr(0, mysvg.length - 1) + "z";
```

Answer (score 1):

You might take a slightly longer trip in your conversion, using MapBox's [wellknown](https://github.com/mapbox/wellknown) library to convert WKT to GeoJSON and then use [D3](http://d3js.org/) to display the GeoJSON as SVG Path element(s).

Answer (score 1):

Using MapBox's [wellknown](https://github.com/mapbox/wellknown) library to convert WKT to GeoJSON and then use [D3](http://d3js.org/) to display the GeoJSON as SVG Path element(s).

Answer (score 0):

libnfporb has a command-line tool to convert wkt to svg: https://github.com/kallaballa/libnfporb/blob/master/examples/wkt_to_svg.cpp

you need to build the library to use it.

usage: ./wkt_to_svg some.wkt some.svg

(I am the author of libnfporb)